nginx: [warn] 25570#25570: conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
I need to migrate my server from a soon expiring Centos 7 VPS running Apache.  The new VPS is on Ubuntu 24.04. In addition to migrating the server, I'd like to switch from Apache to Nginx.  The following is my configuration and I don't know why I'm getting a "conflicting server name error."  As far as I understood, to alias a subdomain, you put the domain and the subdomain in same server_name line.  Am I mistaken?
server {

server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /var/www/example.com;

index index.html index.php;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }

   location ~* /(\.git|cache|bin|logs|backup|tests)/.*$ { return 403; }
   location ~* /(system|vendor)/.*\.(txt|xml|md|html|yaml|yml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
   location ~* /user/.*\.(txt|md|yaml|yml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
   location ~ /(LICENSE\.txt|composer\.lock|composer\.json|nginx\.conf|web\.config|htaccess\.txt|\.htaccess) { return 403; }

location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
 }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



listen 80;

server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


Use nginx -T (uppercase T) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify where the duplicate server name is being loaded. Is there a backup file left behind by your editor perhaps?

Ah, thank you.  It seems that the default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default had the domain name baked in.  After deleting /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default, all is good.

@RichardSmith, You might consider creating an answer which could then be excepted by OP.

What has Grav got to do with this issue? Please remove the tag.
